# How to map a network drive that is mapped to a PC running Tailscale?

Tags: networking, vpn, remote-desktop, mapped-drive, tailscale

I’ve installed Tailscale and I’ve been able to connect to my work PC from my home PC with RDP. I was also able to map the remote PC's local drives as "Network Locations".

How can I also map the remote's mapped drives to my home PC? I believe that they are NAS servers. Ideally I would simply have to install Tailscale on those, but I don't have permission to do that.

Comment: Have you tried mapping the drive using the tailscale IP address? (visible from your tailscale login page). Regardless of how tailscale works - the normal method of mapping drives is still the same. As long as the other side have a shared folder (and you know the username/password for it) - then you should be able to map it without any issue.

Comment: I have tried this, it doesn't work. It kind of makes sense that it doesn't. The IP is the one from the machine I'm connecting to, not the machine where those drives are. Say my work pc's ip is 10.10.10.1. Mapping to a network drive hosted in 10.10.10.2 would need a different kind of route I would guess.

Comment: I have tailscale too set up at my 2 locations. It works for me... check your firewall maybe and ensure that the file and printer sharing is enabled for the correct thing (private / domain / public - depends on what is your setup - ensuring the tailscale IP is allowed to connect). Or before attempting to map just try going to \\10.10.10.2 (based on your example) and see if you can connect at all. In my case - I had to do that first - get prompted for user/pass - and then I can see the share.

Answer (score 2):

thank you for your help. I reached out to them and they told me what I needed to do. I had to [setup a subnet router](https://tailscale.com/kb/1019/subnets/#setting-up-a-subnet-router) in my work machine. The documentation is misleading in that it tells you that you can only setup a subnet on linux, but I was curious and I look at the CLI and the option was there. The specific command you have to run is `tailscale up --advertise-routes=192.168.110.0/24` where the `192.168.110` is the specific route you want relay and `/24` refers to the IPV4 protocol. This allowed me access all hosts from 0 to 255 in 192.168.110.x. Pretty neat. I know this might be obvious to some of you, but for those looking for help, here it is.